# Object and class structure for a larger project in PHP

Tags: php

Im about to start a large project in PHP. I want the code to be as clean as possible so I've started learning programming with classes & objects. Question is, is this the right way to structure it?

What I was thinking is three main classes. `do`, `get` and `general`

In general i will have a function for connecting to database.
In do i will store all functions that is inserting or updating the database for example:

```
class do
{

function createUser($name){

// Do stuff to create user

}

function like($id){

// Do stuff to like the id

}

}

$do = new do;

$do->like("52");
$do->createUser("Bob");
```

Question is, is this the right way to do this? Will this get sloppy when there are more than 20 functions in `do` or `get`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question will likely be closed, because `is this the right way` is requires a subjective response. Nothing is written on stone about what is right, but as long as you implement DRY, SOLID, SRP OO Principles you will be fine.

Comment: Why do you need classes then? Your code can be substituted with a bunch of functions.

Comment: Simon_eQ where should i ask this question? Zerkms: To keep it clean and easy to work with. Will probably have a database connection in each class and it will be much easier to just have one function for that than to pass the function into a bunch of different functions

Comment: As @Simon_eQ said, this is a best practices question so it may get flagged.  Might I suggest [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) for some good coding standards.  Also, it's not a good idea to use reserved words like "do" for userland code.

Comment: @cwscribner I don't think that he ask about best practice. He just need to know a technical concept he think it may cause some problem in the future.

Comment: @sємsєм I agree that it's an architectural question, but it's still a best practices question.  There is no "right" way to do it.  It's all dependent on the goal of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that an object represents a thing, a noun (and a class is the type of thing); "do" is a verb, which is a pretty big clue that it's not a good choice for an object.

In fact, here, it's more like a namespace of "vaguely action-y functions", in contrast to the "get" namespace of "vaguely retrieval-y functions". Namespaces are cool too, but they should be [static classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), or [actual namespaces](http://php.net/namespace) - you never need to refer to an "instance" of one, they just sit there.

As for "general", you should never, ever, *plan* a catch-all like that; it's like giving up on categorising your code before you started. You might end up with one later, for things you really can't put anywhere, but you should be really disappointed if you do.

The objects in the code you've mentioned here might be:

- the database connection
- a user
- whatever thing it is that `$id` represents

Note that last one: an "ID" is not a thing either, it's an identifier for finding a particular thing.

In `$do->like("52");`, neither `$do` nor `"52"` have any real meaning. But if "52" is the ID of a page, and a user is doing the liking, a (very simple) OO implementation might look like this:

```
$page = Page::getByID("52");
$current_user->like( $page );
```

Or perhaps:

```
$page = Page::getByID("52");
$page->addLike( $current_user );
```

Immediately, the code is more readable, and relationships between your objects become clear. And *that* is why OOP is such a popular paradigm for organising code.

I've stuck to the basics here to get the main idea across; a modern OOP framework would go a lot further than this in turning things into objects; for instance:

- "factories" and "repositories" allow creating and loading/saving objects without that static `getByID` call
- a db connection object would be passed into objects that needed it, rather than them assuming they can create their own, which is known as "dependency injection"

Comment: `static`s have no place in proper OOP

Comment: @PeeHaa I thought that as I was proof-reading my answer, and actually wrote up an advanced example with a UserRepository and dependency injected DB connection, but it ended up looking rather intimidating for a beginner, so I thought I'd stick to the basics, and discarded it. And I figure `Page::getByID("52")` is a teeny bit better than having it as the constructor signature (`new Page("52")`).

Comment: @PeeHaa I've added some prose briefly mentioning the things I *haven't* shown, just so that it's clear that this isn't the *best* way this could be OOPified.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, as a personal preference, that classes and objects are a great way to go. However, you're probably going to want to change "do" and "get" into "changes" and "retrievals" or something equally meaningful to you. Using keywords as class names is considered a really evil practice.